# ImportError: cannot import name 'XBee'

Tags: python, python-3.x, xbee

I want to receive data form an Xbee to an other Xbee which is connect to my pc (windows 10). But i can't import the xbee library needed. I install the librairy with : 
    `pip install xbee`

Here is my code :

```
import serial
from xbee import XBee

serial_port = serial.Serial('COM4', 9600)
xbee2 = XBee(serial_port)

while True:
    try:
        reponse = xbee2.wait_read_frame()
        print (reponse)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break

serial_port.close()
```

I took the code from : https://python-xbee.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\mis\Desktop\xbee.py", line 2, in <module>
      from xbee import XBee
   File "C:\Users\mis\Desktop\xbee.py", line 2, in <module>
     from xbee import XBee
ImportError: cannot import name 'XBee'
```

Could somebody help me,
Thanks in advance

Comment: I just did `pip install XBee` from Windows 10 Power Shell and it worked. You could try that if that's not what you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a simple one; looking at your error, it seems that the script you're working on is called `xbee.py`.

The library you're trying to import is also called `xbee`.

So, Python is getting a bit confused, it's trying to import XBee from the script you're working in I suspect (I think the module searching mechanism looks in the local folder first).

If you rename your script from `xbee.py` to something else `test_xbee.py` for example, you should be fine.